# how can I use compare() ( not operator < ()) function in c++ stl map(or set) as a comparator

Tags: c++, stl

First of all, forgive me for my poor English.

---

I know how to use about operator < () and operator()

but, this is not efficient in some case, I think

e.g.  there is a container like this

```
const int c_DataSize = 10;

struct SA
{
    int Data[c_DataSize];

    SA(const int Data_[c_DataSize])
    {
        memcpy(Data, Data_, c_DataSize*sizeof(int));
    }

    bool operator < (const SA& sa_) const
    {
        for(int i=0; i<c_DataSize; ++i)
        {
            if(Data[i] < sa_.Data[i])
                return true;
            else if(Data[i] > sa_.Data[i])
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

set<SA> Container;
```

and, two variables initialized like this

```
int data1[c_DataSize] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}; 
int data2[c_DataSize] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

SA a1(data1);
SA a2(data2);
```

and, when insert these variables into container
Container uses "operator <" one or more times at every insertion. like this,

```
// this is pseudocode
if(data1 < data2)        // (1)
    // data1 < data2
else if(data2 < data1)   // (2) inefficient ( do not need to compare Data[0]~Data[8] )
    // data1 > data2
else
    // data1 == data2
```

in this case, second operation (2) is inefficient I think

because 0 ~ 8 datas already checked in (1).

so, I want to use another function for comparator like this,

```
const int c_DataSize = 10;

// this is better comparator for this structure ( I think )
// like std::string::compare()
int compare(const SA& lhs_, const SA& rhs_) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i<c_DataSize; ++i)
    {
        if (lhs_.Data[i] < rhs_.Data[i])
            return -1;
        else if (lhs_.Data[i] > rhs_.Data[i])
            return 1;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

this function can check by one time execution for comparison. like this,

```
// this is pseudocode
switch(compare(data1, data2))
{
    case -1:
        // data1 < data2
        break;
    case 0:
        // data1 == data2
        break;
    case 1:
        // data1 > data2
        break;
}
```

**My first question is**


How can I use comparator function like SA::compare()
or
Is there another efficient way to compare ( in this case )
or
Is my thought incorrect?

**Second question is**


Is std::set efficient? (I've checked that this doesn't use compare() function)
If not
Is there another efficient way to compare?

In this case ( c_DataSize == 10 )
I don't need compare() function.
but, c_DataSize will be greater than 100
and 100000000(or more) Datas will be inserted at one time every day.
so, I want to know fastest way to insert.

---

**Thank you very much for answer for my questions.**

**-------------------------------------- Added_1 -----------------------------------------**

**Here's another full code. (VS2013 Release) ( checking operator call count )**

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

using TData = __int32;

enum EData
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Max
};

struct SData
{
    TData Datas[EData::Max];

    SData()
    {
    }
    SData(const SData& Data_)
    {
        memcpy(Datas, Data_.Datas, Max*sizeof(TData));
    }

    bool operator < (const SData& Data_) const
    {
        cout << "comp" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < EData::Max; ++i)
        {
            if (Datas[i] < Data_.Datas[i])
                return true;
            else if (Datas[i] > Data_.Datas[i])
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

set<SData> Container;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SData Data;

    Data.Datas[EData::Value1] = 0;
    Data.Datas[EData::Value2] = 0;
    Container.emplace(Data);    // (a)

#if 1
    Data.Datas[EData::Value2] = 1;
    Container.emplace(Data);    // (b1)  called operator < () two times
#else
    Data.Datas[EData::Value2] = -1;
    Container.emplace(Data);    // (b2)  called operator < () one time
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

output  case Release!!(b1)

```
comp
comp
```

output  case Release!!(b2)

```
comp
```

Comment: This is the way the standard sorted containers work. If you don't like it you'll need to write your own. I'm sure most libraries are written to minimize the number of times the comparison function is called, more so than your naive example.

Comment: Second question, unless ordering is important you may find considerably better performance with [`std::unordered_set<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) if you data type hashes well.

Comment: thank you :)

I'll think about hash.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the efficiency of STL. std::set use R-B tree and the operation(2) is not needed. This is part of insert function of STL R-B tree:

```
while (__x != 0) {
    __y = __x;
    __comp = _M_key_compare(_KeyOfValue()(__v), _S_key(__x));
    __x = __comp ? _S_left(__x) : _S_right(__x);
    }
```

You can see there is only one comparision.

As for your program, use operator<() is ok.

For your added question:

Such output will occur only when the set has only one element before insertion. It is a special case and should be ignored.

Comment: thank you for answer. and suggestion. :)

I edited question for you.

please check it and help me again.

thanks.

Comment: @Ryu I compile&run your code use VS2013 but both called `operator < () `two times.

Comment: sorry!, I fixed code. ( memcpy(Datas, Data_.Datas, Max*sizeof(TData)); )

and, you have to build release.

thanks :)